# SQL Server Decimal Operation is Not Accurate

Tags: sql-server, decimal, division

When I run this simple operation in SQL server:

```
Select 800.0 /30.0
```

I get the value 26.666666, where even if it rounds for 6 digits it should be 26.666667.
How can I get the calculation to be accurate? I tried to search about it online and I found a solution where I cast each operand to a high precision decimal before the operation, but this will not be convenient for me because I have many long complex calculations.  think there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

When a using division, in SQL Server, any digits after the resulting scale are truncated, not rounded. For your expression you have a `decimal(4,1)` and a `decimal(3,1)`, which results in a `decimal(10,6)`:

```
Precision = p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
Scale = max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

As a result, `26.66666666666666~` is truncated to `26.666666`.

You can get around this by can increasing the size of the precision and scale, and then `CONVERT` back to your required precision and scale.  For example, increase the precision and scale of the `decimal(3,1)` to `decimal(5,2)` and convert back to a `decimal(10,6)`:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10,6),800.0 / CONVERT(decimal(5,3),30.0));
```

This returns `26.666667`.

Comment: But what if I have a long equation, like x*y/z/w*60/8. Then casting each variable in the equation will be inconvenient

Comment: You don't have to convert them all, @AbdalwhabBakheet . Notice I only convert one value, `30.0`.

Comment: you also converted the output of the division operation, what if I have a list of operations like ((a+b)/c*d)/e?

Comment: I converted one value, and then converted the whole expression back to the desired datatype, @AbdalwhabBakheet . I didn't convert `800.0` at all. LIkely, in that scenario, you would convert the value of `e`.

Answer (score 0):

This might helpful:

Use [ROUND (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT ROUND(800.0 /30.0, 5) AS RoundValue;
```

Result:

```
RoundValue

26.666670
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because SQL Server takes your numbers as `decimal` values (which are exact e.g., 6.6666 and 6.6667 means exactly those values, not 6 and two-thirds) rather than `float` values (which can work with approximate numbers).

If you explicity cast/convert it to a `float` at the start, you should get your calculations running smoothly.

Here's some examples to demonstrate the difference between `int`, `decimal`, and `float` calculations

- Dividing 20 by 3
- Dividing 20 by 3, then multiplying by 3 again (which mathematically should be 20).

```
SELECT  (20/3)                             AS int_calc,
        (20/3) * 3                         AS int_calc_x3,
        (CAST(20 AS decimal(10,3)) /3)     AS dec_calc,
        (CAST(20 AS decimal(10,3)) /3) * 3 AS dec_calc_x3,
        (CAST(20 AS float) /3)             AS float_calc,
        (CAST(20 AS float) /3) * 3         AS float_calc_x3
```

with the following results

```
int_calc   int_calc_x3   dec_calc   dec_calc_x3   float_calc         float_calc_x3
6         18             6.666666   19.999998     6.66666666666667   20
```

In your case, you can use

```
Select CAST(800.0 AS float) /30.0
```

which results in 26.6666666666667

Note if you then multiply back by 30, it gets the correct result e.g.,

```
Select (CAST(800.0 AS float) /30.0) * 30
```

results in 800. Solutions dealing with decimals will not have this.

Note also that once you have it as a float, then it should stay a float until converted back to a decimal or an int somehow (e.g., saved in a table as an int).  So...

```
SELECT A.Num / 30
FROM (Select ((CAST(800.0 AS float) /30.0) * 30) AS Num) AS A
```

will still result in 26.6666666666667

This will hopefully help you in your long complex calculations.