# T-SQL Rounding Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help in solving an issue in rounding decimals in T-SQL.

Amounts in my calculation: 7.34 & 6.16 - Column Datatype smallmoney

Percentages used in calculation: 56.25 & 43.75 - Column Datatype Decimal (5,2)

Using CAST((Amount * Percentage)/100) AS NUMERIC(36,2)) is having an issue for $6.16 because the total shows as 6.17 when rounded. I have tried other datatypes smallmoney, money, decimal and run into the same problem.

Sample code

```
-- Smallmoney and Decimal(5,2) are datatypes of the columns in the table

declare @amount smallmoney = 7.34
declare @amount2 smallmoney = 6.16
declare @percent1 decimal(5,2) = 56.25
declare @percent2 decimal(5,2) = 43.75
declare @total NUMERIC(36,2)
declare @total2 NUMERIC(36,2)

select cast((@amount * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) 
select cast((@amount * @percent2)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2))

select cast((@amount * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) + cast((@amount * @percent2)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) -- Total is 7.34. This is correct.

select cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2))
select cast((@amount2 * @percent2)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2))


select cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) + cast((@amount2 * @percent2)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) -- Total is 6.17. I need this to be 6.16
```

I need to produce a summary and detail reports. See sample below

```
drop table #percentconfig, #transdata, #detailreport

create table #percentconfig(Id int, Name varchar(30), perct decimal(5,2))
insert into #percentconfig values (1, '56 percent', 56.25)
insert into #percentconfig values (1, '43 percent', 43.75)

create table #transdata(transId int, LinkId int, Amount smallmoney)

insert into #transdata values (1, 1, 7.34)
insert into #transdata values (2, 1, 6.16)

select TransId, cast((t.Amount * p.perct)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) as Amount 
into #detailreport
from #percentconfig p 
inner join #transdata t on p.Id = t.LinkId -- This is my query that produces the report.

select TransId, Amount from #transdata -- Summary Report
select TransId, Amount TotalAmount from #detailreport -- Detail Report
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this issue?

Comment: What do you consider wrong in the results you are getting for `$6.16`?

Comment: I have clarified it further with sample code

Comment: *"This works in certain circumstances but not always"* SQL doesn't return diffierent results if you have the same input values and setting, it will return the same values. That means that if it works sometimes and others not, then *something* is different., As for the image, that's of a spreadsheet, not SQL, Excel's rounding can different to SQL Servers; especially when it's not rounding but truncating (which is a very different thing).

Comment: CAST AS NUMERIC(36,2) works for 7.34 but not for 6.16 is what I meant. The code is the same for any amount that we do the calc. For amounts like 6.16 after the calculation the total adds to 6.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you requirement is that all of the results have to add up to the original value (common for calculating taxes), you just can't round each value.
You need to look into rounding of previous calculation and round up or down depending on how previous rounding worked.
For calculation with 2 percentages following formula will work:

```
declare @amount2 smallmoney = 6.16
declare @percent1 decimal(5,2) = 56.25
declare @percent2 decimal(5,2) = 43.75

select cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2))
--select cast((@amount2 * @percent2)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2))
select cast(@amount2 - cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) AS NUMERIC(36,2))

select cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) + cast(@amount2 - cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) AS NUMERIC(36,2)) -- The total here 6.17. I need 6.16
```

Answer (score 0):

The question really is not about the datatypes, but about the rounding itself.

We can simplify your test case as something like this:

```
select cast(0.465 as numeric(36,2)) 
     + cast(0.535 as numeric(36,2))
```

The sum of the two original value is `1`. However, summing then two rounded values does not guarantee that you get back the original value. The first `cast` returns `0.47`, and the second one gives `0.54`, so the sum evaluates as `1.01`.

If you want a safe round trip, then sum first, then cast:

```
select cast(0.465 + 0.535 as numeric(36,2))
```

For your example query, that would be:

```
select cast(
    @amount2 * @percent1 / 100 + @amount2 * @percent2 /100  
    as numeric(36,2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a very similar question posted recently - see the question here [SQL Server Decimal Operation is Not Accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541227/sql-server-decimal-operation-is-not-accurate)
and my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547227/14267425

Also note that [DECIMAL and NUMERIC data types are the synonymous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (e.g., `decimal(5,2)` is the same as `numeric(5,2)`) so it doesn't matter which you use.

The key thing is that decimal (including 'money' types) are *exact* in that once it calculates a value as, say, 6.66, then it treats at as *exactly* 6.66 further. This means, for example, that (20.0 / 3) * 3 potentially ends up as 19.999998 because it considers 20.0/3 = 6.666666 (depending on the number of decimal points it uses).

In your example, when you calculate

```
select cast((@amount2 * @percent1)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) + cast((@amount2 * @percent2)/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2))
```

- it calculates (and rounds to exact value) each of the components
- then adds them together.

The simplest option here is to add them first, then round to the dollar values at the end e.g.,

```
select cast( ((@amount2 * @percent1)/100 + (@amount2 * @percent2)/100) AS NUMERIC(36,2))
```

However, you need to be really careful about when you do your conversions/rounding. For cash (e.g., money in hand) this is actually appropriate - you cannot give someone half a cent. However for banks and % transactions, this can be problematic.

I suggest trying `float` type variables for calculations where you want inexact values (like 6 and 2/3) then convert to `decimal` when you want to make it 'concrete'.

An alternative to using `float` values/datatypes, is to use a `decimal` with more decimal points (higher precision) than you need.

For example, if your data is in dollars and cents, you may do your calculations in `decimal(18,4)` so it has 4 decimal points - effectively doing calculations at 1/100th of a cent. Then when you make it 'concrete' as above, you round it to 2 decimal points e.g., `decimal(18,2)` representing exact dollars and cents.

Note that decimals with higher precision is occurring with your data set above e.g., the when doing the calculations with percentages, it adds precision to get more decimal points than what you need e.g., `select (@amount2 * @percent1)/100` results in `3.4650000000`

However, if you're doing it with a value with repeating decimals (e.g., splitting a $20.00 lunch bill across 3 people) the automatic precision updates won't cope and will round to a decimal. If you're only ever dividing by 100, this won't be an issue as it will just shift decimal places 2 places. However, if you want weekly averages (dividing by 52) or daily (dividing by 365 etc) it is quite likely you will run into some rounding issues.

Therefore, you need to be conscious of what type/precision of values are being used at what point in calculations, and control them to ensure they represent what they need to in real life.

The strategy is to use the higher precision decimals or floats for calculations you want to be take more detailed fractions into account, then round/convert the values when appropriate.
e.g.,

- You're a shop, running a sale of 30% off on certain items (and working in dollars and cents)
- You calculate the 30% off as `float` or high-precision `decimal` values, so you get the exact amounts rather than someone abusing it to get a few cents extra (or, alternatively, they don't get a big enough discount) when you get the total
- When you get to the total, you convert it to `decimal(18,2)` so it's exact - as it represents the actual amount you are charging the customer. If you left it as a `float`, it may have a phantom fraction of a cent in the value, that creates an error when you total across all the day's sales.

Comment: I agree with your comment "However for banks and % transactions, this can be problematic". This is actually equal to a bank transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code as below based on Pitor and GMB suggestion. This gives the expected result.

```
drop table #percentconfig, #transdata, #detailreport, #detailreport2

create table #percentconfig(Id int, Name varchar(30), perct decimal(5,2))
insert into #percentconfig values (1, '56 percent', 56.25)
insert into #percentconfig values (1, '43 percent', 43.75)

create table #transdata(transId int, LinkId int, Amount smallmoney)

insert into #transdata values (1, 1, 7.34)
insert into #transdata values (2, 1, 6.16)

select TransId, t.Amount AS FullAmt, p.Perct as Percentage, 
CASE WHEN (100 - p.perct) > p.perct THEN cast(t.Amount - cast((t.Amount * (100 - p.perct))/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) AS NUMERIC(36,2)) 
ELSE CAST(t.Amount * p.perct/100  AS NUMERIC(36,2)) END as Amount
into #detailreport
from #percentconfig p 
inner join #transdata t on p.Id = t.LinkId -- This is my query that produces the report.

select * from #transdata -- Summary Report
select * from #detailreport order by transId-- Detail Report
```